# insertAfter within a loop

Tags: jquery, loops, insertafter

I have some code generated by a CMS:

```
<div class="block">
  <a class="link" href="#">Link</a>
  <h4>Header here</h4>
  <div class="text">Some text here</div>
</div>
```

and I need to move the link to after the text div. I have tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.block').each(function() {
            $('.block a.link').insertAfter('.block div.text');                      
        });
    });
```

but this only results in links being repeated about 10 times (the number of times looped.

I tried using $(this) but I don't quite understand how to write the correct syntax to append the a.link within the function... like this:

```
 $(this).a.link.insertAfter($(this).div.text);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this should work, using `siblings` and `after`:

```
$('.block a.link').each(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.text').after(this);
});
```

That says "for each element matched, find the element that matches `.text` and insert the original element after it".

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
$('.block a.link').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().append(this);
});
```

This presumes that you want to put the element at the end of the `div.block`.

Comment: Thanks @lonesomeday - I think putting it to the end of the block div is a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

You could do (if you want it after the div with class text):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.block a').each(function(){
       $(this).next('div.text').after(this);
    });
   });
```

or (if you want it after the div with class block)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.block a').each(function(){
       $(this).closest('div.block').after(this);
    });
   });
```

Comment: Thanks @Nicola Peluchetti - I don't want it after the block, but it's good to know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.block').each(function() {
                var divtext = $('div.text', this)
                $('a.link', this).insertAfter(divText);
            });
});
```

Comment: Thank @Cybernate - another method I didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('div.block a.link').each(function() {
    $(this).siblings('div.text').after(this);
});
```